# Pandas - group, sort and keep first row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe I need to group by `id`, then sort by `time` and keep only the first record for each `id`. Tried different methods suggested in other answers but couldn't get the right result. Will be grateful for your help!

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,
                           2,2,
                           3,3,3,3],
                   'ref'  : ["search","social","direct",
                          "social","direct",
                          "direct",'social','social','social'],
                   'media':['video', 'page', 'video',
                           'page', 'pic', 
                            'pic', 'video', 'page', 'video'],
                   'time': ['2019-04-10 19:00:00.569', '2019-04-10 00:10:00.569', '2019-04-10 00:10:20.569',
                          '2019-04-10 12:10:00.569','2019-04-10 11:10:00.569',
                          '2019-04-10 22:10:00.569','2019-04-10 14:10:00.569','2019-04-10 14:30:00.569','2019-04-10 15:10:00.569']})
```

Expected result:

```
    id  ref     media
0   1   social  page
1   2   direct  pic
2   3   social  video
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can sort and then drop duplicates:

```
test.sort_values(by=['id', 'time']).drop_duplicates('id').drop('time',1)

   id     ref  media
1   1  social   page
4   2  direct    pic
6   3  social  video
```